# Java (2D) animation library

Tags: java, animation, desktop-application

I'm creating (for a semester project) a Java desktop application. The aim is to provide a rich and intuitive user interface. I'm now looking for Java cross-platform library that works with Swing and provides animations (moving, resizing, rotation, color/alpha change and other 2D stuff).
Basically, I'm looking for an equivalent of [CoreAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/coreanimation/) in the JavaWorld.

I found [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home), but have no experience with it and no development seems to have taken place since mid-2010.

Does anyone of you have experience with Trident or can recommend a library that fits what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi 
I have no deep knowledge of this but I had a look at trident a year ago and it looked well designed, feature complete and stable.

I would go with that one if you find nothing better. You have to browse the blog of Kiril at pushingpixels.org to get some additional good examples.

Have fun,
- Rossi

Answer (score 1):

Use `libgdx` awesome library!!

Comment: That rather looks like a library specifically designed for games. I'm looking for an animation library for user interfaces...